# Recording internal sound and microphone with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio, microphone, speaker, wasapi

I need to record an internal sound and microphone sound simultaneously. So, I'm using 2 parallel tasks:
`WasapiLoopbackCapture` class for an internal sound recording and `WaveInEvent` class for microphone sound recording.

It works good for computer's speakers and microphone, also it works with aux headset.
The problem is when I use Bluetooth headset - it records an internal sound and microphone sound simultaneously, but I **can't hear** an internal sound in headset during recording. If I use only `WasapiLoopbackCapture` class for an internal sound recording it works as needed, so I think the problem is in `WaveInEvent` class (it looks like it "mutes" internal sound).

Did someone face such a problem? How can I solve it?

**===== UPDATE =====**

I'm sure it's BT headset microphone recording issue ONLY.
I tried this command:

```
./ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Headset (HD 350BT Hands-Free AG Audio)" C:\\tmp\\1.wav
```

It returns the same result. BT microphone sound was recorded but internal sound was muted/interrupted and I didn't hear it in my BT headset.

Comment: When you say "internal sound", do you mean you want to record the sound the computer is outputting?

Comment: Yes. Youtube video, for example.